# Porter duff "conjoint" and "disjoint" use cases in vulkan

Tags: image-processing, vulkan, alphablending

I'm trying to implement manual porter-duff composite blending, partially based off the [Vulkan spec](https://docs.vulkan.org/spec/latest/chapters/framebuffer.html#framebuffer-blend-advanced).   however I'm very confused by a few parts in  Vulkan's advanced blending extension.  Mainly, beyond where the equation comes from the first place (not in the actual porter duff paper afaict, but I see referenced with out a source in various forms in other locations), the `VK_BLEND_OVERLAP_UNCORRELATED_EXT`, `VK_BLEND_OVERLAP_CONJOINT_EXT`, and `VK_BLEND_OVERLAP_DISJOINT_EXT` enums.

As I understand, `VK_BLEND_OVERLAP_UNCORRELATED_EXT` is the "default", the version I see implicitly in other sources, for example in the [SVG compositing spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVGCompositing/)

```
Dca' = f(Sc, Dc) × Sa × Da  + Y × Sca × (1-Da)  + Z × Dca × (1-Sa)
Da'  =         X × Sa × Da  + Y × Sa × (1-Da)   + Z × Da × (1-Sa)
```

which is basically equivalent to

```
Dca' = f(Sc, Dc) × p0  + Y × Sc x p1  + Z × Dc x p2
Da'  =         X × p0  + Y × p1       + Z × p2
```

where

- `p0 = source alpha * destination alpha`
- `p1 = source alpha * (1.0 - destination alpha)`
- `p2 = destination alpha * (1.0 - source alpha)`

matching `VK_BLEND_OVERLAP_UNCORRELATED_EXT` coefficients.

Equations for the others are

`VK_BLEND_OVERLAP_CONJOINT_EXT`

- `p0 = min(source alpha, destination alpha)`
- `p1 = max(source alpha - destination alpha, 0.0)`
- `p2 = max(destination alpha - source alpha, 0.0)`

`VK_BLEND_OVERLAP_DISJOINT_EXT`

- `p0 = max(source alpha + destination alpha - 1.0, 0.0)`
- `p1 = min(source alpha, (1.0 - destination alpha))`
- `p2 = min(destination alpha, (1.0 - source alpha))`

While I physically see the equations for the other enums, I don't understand where they come from or what their purpose is.

Vulkan spec states:

```
* VK_BLEND_OVERLAP_UNCORRELATED_EXT specifies that there is no correlation between the source and destination coverage.

* VK_BLEND_OVERLAP_CONJOINT_EXT specifies that the source and destination coverage are considered to have maximal overlap.

* VK_BLEND_OVERLAP_DISJOINT_EXT specifies that the source and destination coverage are considered to have minimal overlap.
```

but I don't know what the importance of that is.

I'm ultimately trying to figure out how to add a seperate *alpha blending* operation in addition to color blending `(f(Sc,Dc))`, with out a special enum to handle blend overlap.  But with these extra modes, I don't know how to properly account for arbitrary functions for alpha blending.